Touch screen in Ubuntu 24.04 and battery consumption in thinkpad t480s
i have thinkpad t480s i5-8350u 12gb ram 256gb ssd with touch screen with full hd and windows 11. I plan to install Ubuntu 24.04.
Will Ubuntu handle the touch panel well enough to not be an obstacle to working freely and will it not be a problem?
Does ubuntu 24.04 consume a lot of battery?
I need a laptop for lectures and everyday work
